# Как сделать разные стили под разные посты?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу чтоб при добавлении поста, было 2 разных стиля. Как можно заметить на скриншоте, у первого поста картинка слева, а текст справа, у второго поста наоборот. Статическую верстку я могу сделать такого варианта, а вот как сделать, чтоб была динамика при добавлении нового поста, стили менялись поочередно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте для `:odd` и `:even` - наиболее удобный нативный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте псевдоклассы CSS `:nth-child(even)` и `:nth-child(odd)`.
Селекторы с этими псевдоклассами соответствуют чётным и нечётным элементам. Например:

```css
.post:nth-child(even) /* все чётные посты */
{
    ...
}
```

Это наиболее удобный нативный вариант.

Подробнее [тут](http://htmlbook.ru:8080/css/nth-child)